# Linux cat command is not working properly in python

Tags: python

I have written a script to get some information from  a file.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import pxssh
 import os
 import sys
 path = os.getcwd()
 conf = sys.argv[1]
 print type(path)
 print type(conf)
 print path
 print conf
 HOST_IP=os.system("cat %s/%s | grep 'HOST_IP'| cut -d '=' -f2")%(path,conf)
```

Here is the error I am getting .

```
`[root@135 bin]# ./Jboss64.py ../conf/samanoj.conf
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
/root/Sanity/bin
../conf/samanoj.conf   --> This is the file present under conf folder
cat: %s/%s: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Jboss64_EA_EM_FM.py", line 11, in <module>
    LIVEQ_HOST_IP=os.system("cat %s/%s | grep 'LIVEQ_HOST_IP'| cut -d '=' -f2")%(path,conf)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'tuple'`
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Move the `)` after `f2"` to the end of the line?

Comment: why isn't anyone marking this as an *exact duplicate* of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'tuple' when executing a command with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761306/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-tuple-when-executing-a) ?

Comment: @PaulPanzer wouldn't you mark this question as a duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

You should write like that:

```
os.system("cat %s/%s | grep 'HOST_IP'| cut -d '=' -f2" % (path,conf))
```

In your expression, first is executed os.system, only after that executing format string operator.
os.system return `0` that's why you got this error

Would be better if you use format method:

```
os.system("cat {}/{} | grep 'HOST_IP'| cut -d '=' -f2".format(path, conf))
```

Also would be better if you use subprocess.Popen instead of os.system

```
Popen("cat {}/{} | grep 'HOST_IP'| cut -d '=' -f2".format(path, conf), shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things that may help:

1. `os.system` is being deprecated, I suggest you use `subprocess.Popen`
   Docs here:https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html
2. Where you have:

   `LIVEQ_HOST_IP=os.system("cat %s/%s | grep 'LIVEQ_HOST_IP'| cut -d '=' -f2")%(path,conf)`

it may be easier to construct the string in Python, then pass to bash.  So something like:

```
output_str = "cat " +str(path) + "/" + str(conf) + " | grep 'LIVEQ_HOST_IP'| cut -d '=' -f2" 
LIVEQ_HOST_IP=subprocess.Popen(output_str)
```

`subprocess` (and `os`) take a string that is used to call system functions, so make sure that the string is correct before you pass to `Popen`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Why did you replace `%` with `+`? The only mistake in the example code was that the `%` was in the wrong place.

Comment: Habit i guess, i just prefer to concatenate something so i can print it before sending it to processes.  Find it a bit safer especially when I'm moving files around. It's not necessary to re-write it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
cmd = "cat {}/{} | grep 'HOST_IP'| cut -d '=' -f2".format(str(path), str(conf))
HOST_IP = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```